# How to make react-native DatePickerIOS in 24 hours format?

Tags: react-native

[image: DatePickerIOS]

I am learning react-native. How to remove AM/PM and use 24 hours format in DatePickerIOS?

Here is my code

```
class ClockScreen extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      date: new Date(),
      timeZoneOffsetInHours: (-1) * (new Date()).getTimezoneOffset() / 60,
    };
  }

  render() {
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <DatePickerIOS
            date={this.state.date}
            mode="time"
            timeZoneOffsetInMinutes={this.state.timeZoneOffsetInHours * 60}
            onDateChange={this.onDateChange.bind(this)}
          />
        </View>
      );
  }

  onDateChange(date) {
    this.setState({date: date});
  }
}
```

Comment: By default it'll use the phone's current locale's default date settings. E.g. in France you'd see 24hrs, and UK 12hrs + AM/PM.

Answer (score 10):

Time 24h formate depend on locale props and default locale's set "en".

Add this props locale={'en_GB'}

```js
 <DatePickerIOS
   date={new Date()}
   locale={'en_GB'}
 >
```

Comment: This has the annoying side-effect of displaying the date selection in the British fashion.  "Thurs 14 Oct" instead of "Thurs Oct 14".  Going to try to find a way to get American date selection with 24 hour format.